# Statistical tests in BigQuery: how can I run a binomial test?

Tags: sql, statistics, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

It would be useful to have advanced statistical functions in BigQuery. How can I get Bayesian credible intervals and binomial tests?

Are there any UDFs available?

Comment: based on http://www.ocadotechnology.com/our-blog/articles/statistical-testing-in-google-bigquery, since the author is here too

Answer (score 4):

You can write [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)s for that. It's not that complicated actually, although it can be a bit messy to debug them. Here's a [link](https://github.com/backlin/resources/tree/master/statistical-testing-in-BQ) to some UDFs I've written for binomial tests and Bayesian credible intervals, and below is a short demo of how you use them. If you use the web interface don't forget to paste them into the UDF editor, which you find by pressing the button to the top right of the query textbox.

Let's say you grow strawberries that are picked into boxes by part time workers.  On average 1 out of 100 boxes is rejected by the customers because it contains too many bad berries. You decide to give a bonus to the best picker, but realise that comparing them by the raw rejection rate will give an unfair edge to pickers with few boxes (since 0 rejections out of 10 boxes is not necessarily better than 1 rejection out of 100 boxes). Instead you use a [binomial test](https://github.com/backlin/resources/blob/master/statistical-testing-in-BQ/binomial_test.js) to calculate who is the most likely to be better than the average:

```
SELECT
   id,
   pvalue
 FROM
   binomial_test(
     SELECT
       *
     FROM
       (SELECT "Jim" AS id,  234 AS total, 0 AS observed, 1/100 AS probability),
       (SELECT "Bob" AS id, 1478 AS total, 3 AS observed, 1/100 AS probability),
       (SELECT "Sue" AS id,  482 AS total, 1 AS observed, 1/100 AS probability)
   )
```

```
Row  id   pvalue     
1    Jim  0.09519969035921706    
2    Bob  2.408837505151057E-4   
3    Sue  0.04620667666995042
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the probability field from the input of the function...

Comment: @DavidBrophy: Fixed now.